# search for date values in string

Tags: php, regex

this my situation at the moment:
I save a dynamic string into a variable $content.

With this code I get all values of my $content which has the number format x.xx

```
preg_match_all('/\d+\,\d+/m', $content, $matches);
```

Now I would like to get additionally all values which are dates.
For example:

```
14.10.2021
10/14/2021
10. October 2021
```

The year could be also like 21 instead of 2021.
Here are many version possible.

Is there also a preg_match_all solution for that?
Or is there an way to say:

Give me all values of the string, where php found a valid date?

Thank you a lot !!

Comment: So `$content` can be a string like `something something foo 10/14/2021 bar 10/14/20 and more foo 10. October 2021 ...` ?

Comment: To check if string is valid date you can use just new DateTime('your string'); and if creating new instance of DateTime will not throw Exception that mean your string is ok.

Comment: `a valid date` is a very broad statement. `1.1.1` would be a date? `1.1.1 1:1:1` as well?

Comment: What is the status of yeterday's regex question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `DateTime` class is generally a good idea to work with dates but I guess that you need to extract them as your string does not only contain dates.
Using a RegEx results in long patterns because of months:

```regex
\d{2}(\.|\/)?(\d{2}\1|\s(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)\s)(\d{4}|\d{2})
```

But it matches the following:

- `\d{2}` 2 digits
- `(\.|\/)?` an optional dot or slash (group capture n°1)
- `(`

  - `\d{2}\1` 2 digits followed by group capture n°1
  - `|` or
  - `\s(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)\s` a month with spaces around
- `)`
- `(\d{4}|\d{2})` 2 or 4 digits

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work. `preg_match_all('\d{2}(\.|\/)(\d{2}\1|\s(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)\s)(\d{4}|\d{2})', $content, $matches);` But result will be empty. My String contains the following: `Lieferdatum 05 Oktober 2021 Rechnungsnumme`

Comment: sorry my fault: string contains `Lieferdatum 05 October 2021 Rechnungsnummer`

Comment: @Ghost108 updated, I made the group capture n°1 optional.

Comment: same result :((

Comment: @Ghost108  but it works: https://regex101.com/r/SRqIm2/1 or the PHP implementation https://3v4l.org/mRZl5

Comment: yes but this isn't correct. only the first value of your array is okay, but the rest is empty or only month / year :( But I think your solution is good. If I only get the value of $matches[0] it seams to be perfect ! :)

Comment: @Ghost108 that's how `preg_match_all()` works, the first key is for the whole match and then you get a key per capture group. I can't change that, hehe ! You can accept my answer if it solves the problem :)